# Getting Error Array Type Required

Tags: delphi

I am trying to run this code:

```
RichViewEdit1.LineCount[i]:= Cipher.EncryptString(RichViewEdit1.LineCount[i]);
```

And I keep getting an error: Array Type Required.

Why I'm I getting this error?

**More Info:**

LineCount is - System.Integer

And TRichViewEdit does not have a "Lines" property.

Comment: Show us the declaration of type of the property `RichViewEdit1.LineCount` and the declaration of the type of the variable `RichViewEdit1`. We cannot see it in your questions.  PS. Maybe you mistaken `.Lines.Strings[i]` with `.Lines.Count`

Comment: Probably should be Lines[i] instead of LineCount[i], but as Arioch mentioned, it is impossible to understand from the peace of code.

Comment: TRichViewEdit does not have a "Lines" property.:/

Comment: Since "LineCount is System.Integer" you can only assign an integer to the whole property. You cannot assign a string to it and you cannot take i-th element of an unitarian integer data.

Comment: `"TRichViewEdit does not have a "Lines" property"` then look which property it does have instead. You have the sources and can look into them. We don;t have them and cannot look there. Also among the sources look for folders like "demo" or "example" or "sample" - usually there is a ready-made programs that show you all the properties you need

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you use [] on an integer? Programming by guesswork never ends well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `RichViewEdit1.LineCount` is not an array.

What it is ? don't know. Look into your sources, we cannot see them here.

PS. There seem to be no .Line*** properties at all: http://www.trichview.com/help/pme_cp_trichviewedit.html

Dunno if that still is relevant - http://www.trichview.com/support/trichview.support.examples/retrievingtext.htm

Also read through http://www.trichview.com/help/idh_rvgettext.html

PPS. since you paid for the component, you're entitled to get their programming examples and their customer support service. Both this and that are available at http://www.trichview.com/support/

Comment: you're repeating my link ? why ? You asked why you got the compilation error, i told you why it happens.